# Using JS 'if' statements to detect whether an image is dragged to the correct location on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, if-statement, html5-canvas

I have number of 'draggable' images on an HTML5 canvas. There are also a number of 'description box' images displayed on the canvas, and the user is required to drag each of the draggable images to its corresponding description box.

There are four description boxes currently displayed on the canvas, and I have a function which I'm using to detect if an image has been dragged to one of the boxes. Each time an image is dragged to a box, I check whether it's been dragged to the correct box- if it has, the image is then hidden, but if not, it stays visible.

All of the draggable images are stored in a single array, and the way I'm checking whether they are dragged to the correct box is by using their position within the array, i.e. if they are between positions 0-9 in the array, they belong to box 1; if they're in positions 10-19, they belong to box 2, etc.

I'm adding the 'if' statements for each box one at a time, and it is currently working as intended for the first two boxes. I'm now trying to add the code for the third box, but for some reason, when I add this, the code breaks and I get a ReferenceError in the console.

This is what the function currently looks like:

```
function isHit(mouseX, mouseY, obj){
  console.log("isHit has been called from within if statement in mousemove function");
  console.log("draggingImage variable value = " +draggingImage);
  if(draggingImage == true){
    console.log("if dragging image == true statment is being called");
    console.log("Value of selectedImage = " + selectedImage);
    console.log("Value of selectedImageArrayLocation = " + selectedImageArrayLocation);
    if(mouseY > 250){
        //console.log("Value of obj.shape.index = " +obj.shape.index);
        if((mouseX > 80) && (mouseX < 200) && (selectedImageArrayLocation >= 0) && (selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets)){
            console.log("Correct");
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Correct! This is an asset because it is an item that can be bought or sold for cash.";
            selectedImage.hide();
            console.log("selectedImage has been removed: " + selectedImage);
        }else if((mouseX > 80) && (mouseX < 200) && (selectedImageArrayLocation > numImagesAssets)){
            console.log("Incorrect");
            console.log("Selected image array location: " + selectedImageArrayLocation);
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Incorrect! This icon is not an asset. It is not a physical item that would be bought or sold for cash. ";

        }else if((mouseX > 310) && (mouseX < 430) && (selectedImageArrayLocation > numImagesAssets) && (selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities)){
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Correct! This is a liability because it is an item or service that the company is required to make regular payments for. ";
            selectedImage.hide();
            console.log("selectedImage has been removed: " + selectedImage);
        }else if((mouseX > 310) && (mouseX < 430) && ((selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets) || (selectedImageArrayLocation > numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities))){
            console.log("Incorrect. This icon is not a liability.");
            console.log("Selected image array location: " + selectedImageArrayLocation);
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Incorrect! This icon is not a liability. It is not an item or service that the company is required to make regular payments for. ";

        }else if((mouseX > 540) && (mouseX < 660) && ((selectedImageArrayLocation > numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities) && (selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities + numImagesIncome))){
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Correct! This is a source of income because it is a product or service which the company sells to its customers for cash. ";
            selectedImage.hide();
            console.log("Selected image has been removed: " + selectedImage);
        }/*else if((mouseX > 540) && (mouseX < 660) && ((selectedImageArrayLocation <= numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities) && (selectedImageArrayLocation > numImagesAssets + numImagesLiabilities + numImagesIncome))){
            console.log("Incorrect. This icon is not a source of income.");
            console.log("Selected image array location: " + selectedImageArrayLocation);
            document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Incorrect! This icon is not a source of income.");
        } */
    }
  }
}
```

The 'if' statements are in pairs, so the first two belong to the first description box, the second two to the second one, etc.

At the moment, I only have the first 'if' statement working for the third description box... I've written the second 'if' statement for it in exactly the same way as for the previous two description boxes, but for some reason, when I uncomment that 'else if' clause, view my page in the browser, and drag an image to that description box that doesn't belong to it, I get a console error that says:

```
ReferenceError: isHit is not defined
```

That error is complaining about the line:

```
var isItHit = isHit(mouseX, mouseY, obj);
```

which is in my `mousemove` function, which is also being called by all of the other 'if' statements, so I don't understand why it's decided to break when it's called this time... does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, ok, I've spotted what the problem was... In the `document.getElementById` line in the last else if clause, I had a `)` too many. The issue was fixed by changing that line to:

```
document.getElementById('tipsParagraph').innerHTML = "Incorrect! This icon is not a source of income.";
```

i.e. removing the `)` at the end of the line.